# Generating Tree View using SCORM API

Tags: javascript, jquery, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I am completely new in SCORM. I have imsmanifest.xml file and want to display tree view depending upon manifest structure. Is there any API in SCORM which read the provided imsmanifest.xml and generate tree view in HTML???? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a tree view of organisations and items, then no, there is no way via the API to do that.  That goes for both SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004.

As far as I'm aware, the only way to get that data is to get the data from manifest file, but the API does not give access to that.

An alternative is to load the data from the manifest into your database when the package is first uploaded to your LMS.  You can then process that data into whatever format you need, and read it quicker than reading and processing the manifest file each time.

If you're using SCORM 2004, there are loads of rules about how this tree should be displayed.  The spec is here -

http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-2004-4th-Edition-Specification?type=technical_documentation